# Illegal offset type while creating new record in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to create new record using seeder.

This is the code i wrote on seeder file:

```
RoleUser::create(['role_id'=>$roleId[0],'user_id'=>$user->id]);
PermissionRole::create(['permission_id'=>1,'role_id'=>$roleId[0]]);
```

This is the error i am getting

```
[ErrorException] Illegal offset type
```

**RoleUser** model is used for **role_user** table

```
Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->primary(['role_id','user_id']);
    });
```

**PermissionRole** model is used for **permission_role** table

```
Schema::create('permission_role', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('permission_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
        $table->primary(['permission_id','role_id']);
    });
```

**RoleUser** **Model** has following code :

```
    class RoleUser extends Model
{
    protected $table='role_user';
    protected $primaryKey=['role_id','user_id'];
    protected $fillable=['role_id','user_id'];
    public $timestamps=false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out.
The problem occurred because i used following code in RoleUser model :

`protected $primaryKey=['role_id','user_id'];`

Removed this line and now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Illegal offset type errors occur when you attempt to access an array index using an object or an array as the index key.

Probably the error should be how you are getting `$roleId` and `$user`.

You'll have to make sure `$roleId` and `$user` contains what you want it to and that you're accessing it correctly.

Comment: Actually both $user->id and $roleId[0] returning values that i wanted. Same codes working fine with l5.2 but not working on l5.3. Any thoughts?